# 7 - How to Add Custom Error Class to Radio Button and Checklist Fields

Tags: forms, hooks

I created a field with Radio buttons and when it fails to validate, there is no red highlight around it.

[image]

There is only an error message at the top.

[image]

How can I add a custom CSS class to any radio button fields upon a failed validation?

I am already altering this form with hook_form_alter(); and have a custom validation function, so I am willing to work on a custom module for this but just need some help being pointed in the right direction.

I would ideally like to add a ".error" class or something to this div and customize it in my CSS to also give it a red border.

How can this be acheived?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box webforms created with Drupal core and the Webform module do not have in line error messaging and indicators for each form field.

You can either:

- add custom hooks and javascript to get inline validation, or
- install client-side validation module and associated javascript library to get validation/messaging for all standard form elements.  See https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation